# How to integrate swagger with spring cloud function

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-cloud-function

I have one spring boot application having three spring cloud function which I am able to execute via postman or curl successfully .Now my next step is to add swagger documentation for the same. I have followed all configuration that we do to add swagger with normal spring boot project. And it is up and running  but problem is that my functions URL are not listed in swagger since Request Mapping or API operations annotations  are not getting picked up maybe those are just functions not a controller that's y. So if someone could help how to integrate so i can document all cloud functions that I am creating.

Comment: If you could compile a simple (bare minimum) app and push it to github somewhere we can certainly have a look and see what kind of support can we provide or perhaps there is a missing configuration. In any event we need more info and such app would provide that

Comment: I expect springdoc project to support it OOTB
https://springdoc.org/
so all the exposed functions should be visible in Swagger as an endpoints

Comment: I've created issue: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1299